# Question regarding the partial derivative of a solution to an ODE

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm reading a text on dynamical system, where the following fact is stated without proof:

> Let $U$ be an open set bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$, suppose that $\varphi_t$ is a solution to the differential equation $\dot x=f(x)$ such that $\varphi_0(p)=p$ for all $p\in U$, and that it is defined for all $t\in\mathbb R$. Then for $h\in\mathbb R$ small we have $$\frac{\partial \varphi_h(x)}{\partial x}=\operatorname{id}+df(x)h+o(h).$$

The text says this follows from a Taylor expansion around $x$, but I really don't see why this is true.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik sorry, I still don't see your point.

Comment: The text is called "Ergodic Theory and Topological Dynamics of Group Actions on Homogeneous Spaces", here is where the assertion appears: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3zy2.png

Comment: It takes a bit of machinery to prove this, it is not entirely trivial. One way is to study the equation $\phi(x,p) = 0$ where  $\phi(x,p)(t) = x(t)- (p+ \int_0^t f(x(s))ds)$. The implicit function theorem is useful here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is informal but can be formalised with the appropriate assumptions.

One has $x(p,t) = p + \int_0^t f(x(p,s)) ds$, so assuming differentiability we have
${\partial x(p,t) \over \partial p}(t) =I + \int_0^t {\partial f(x(p,s)) \over \partial x} {\partial x(p,s) \over \partial p}(t) ds$.

For small $t$ (wave hands here) we have to first order
${\partial x(p,t) \over \partial p}(t) \approx I + t{\partial f(p) \over \partial x} I $.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the last part.

Comment: For small $t$ the integrand is approx. constant at the $s=0$ value.

Comment: Now I understand this using Taylor expansions. Thank you very much.